# Enterprise Library slidingExpirationTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, enterprise-library

My web application uses enterprise library caching module. I've a config value below for Enterprise Library 4.0.

```
<cacheOptions>
    <add name="Cache" cachePartition="Content" slidingExpirationTime="30" cachePrioriy="High" />
</cacheOptions>
```

If the user clicks 24 times on web page button does it mean that the  caching expiration willl happen only after
24*30min ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what it means is that an item is removed from the cache when it hasn't been accessed for 30 minutes.

Suppose you add an item `A` to the cache at `t0`. If you do not retrieve `A` from the cache for the next 30 minutes, it will be removed at `t0 + 30`. However, suppose you retrieve the item at `t0 + 10`. Now the expiration time 'slides' 10 minutes and your item will be removed at `t0 + 40`.

Cached items are removed 30 minutes after they are last accessed.